# How to dynamically add questions to Vue Webpack template's meta.js file?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I've forked the standard Vue Webpack template and am editing the meta.js file.  I'm trying to find a way to add a property to `prompts` like this:

```
    "pages": {
      "type": "input",
      "required": true,
      "message": "How many pages would you like your template to have?"
     },
```

And thereafter use the `pages` variable to add more questions, like this:

```
"page1": {
  "type": "string",
  "required": true,
  "message": "What would you like to name page1?"
 },
```

I imagine it would look like a loop defined outside of the object that adds properties to the object.  But that would be loaded at the same time as object and the variables would be undefined.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The meta.json content is evaluated by vue-cli, so you would have to fork that and change there.

Are your questions really runtime-dependent, or do you only need contitionals? Because that works, you can find examples of this in the template's questions right now, for example the sub-questions for linting.

Comment: The questions are run-time dependent.  I'd like to have the prompt ask the user the name of a page X number of times, X being the answer to the question to the `pages` question.